# Problema con mysqli `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Tags: php, mysql

Estaba tratando de usar mysqli en mi proyecto, para acceder a una base de datos, pero cuando ejecute el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php

define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
    define("DB_USERNAME", "root");
    define("DB_PASSWORD", "root");
    define("DB_DATABASE", "databasename");
    $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

if(!$db) {
    echo 'error en la conexion';
} else {
    echo 'conexion correcta';
}
```

Me salió el siguiente error:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()`

Busque en stack overflow y decía que en php.ini cambiara el `;extension=mysqli` a `extension=mysqli`

Así que lo hice, reinicie el host y lo volví a ejecutar, pero ahora me sale este error:
`Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Volví a buscar en stack overflow este error y los usuarios decían que este error aparece cuando introducimos mal algún dato, pero no introduje nada mal, el usuario es root y la contraseña también.

Para verificarlo quise entrar a la base de datos de mysql mediante la consola, pero ahora también me aparece este error en la consola. `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Hasta hace poco podía acceder perfectamente a la base de datos, ¿Qué paso?

pd: No uso apache ni xammp ni nada de eso.

Comment: El mensaje es claro. O el usuario o el password son incorrectos. En muchos contextos el password por defecto para root es dejarlo en blanco, prueba poniéndolo así: `define("DB_PASSWORD", "");`

Comment: prueba creando otro usuario para conectarte a la base de datos, si no mal recuerdo el usuario root tiene deshabilitado por defecto el inicio de sesión remoto

Answer (score 0):

La contraseña del usuario root es incorrecta,  prueba dejándola en blanco (en caso de que no tenga contraseña):

```
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
```

O agregando la contraseña correcta.

Comment: Estoy 100% seguro de que la contraseña es root. Ademas ya intente dejandolo en blanco y tampoco funciona.